# can add components dynamically in component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

how can I add components dynamically in component?

notice : i don't want to save component global. i just want to add components locally.

best way for  define problem is show code

```
    export default {
    name: 'tabMaker',
    props: {
        components_: {
            type: Array,
            default: [],
        },
    },
    components: {
        // how can add components dynamically in here ?
    },
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    created() {
        var self=this;
        this.components_.forEach((item)=>{
            Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                // key = component name
                // value = object component
                //  ???? 
                // add component in props in object componenents
                 self.components[key]=value;// not work ? TODO
                 // ?????
            });
        })
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the names of components, e. g. `['comp1', 'comp2']`, then you have to register all the components, that could be passed (`components: {comp1, comp2, comp3...}`), and then you can use this structure:

```
<component v-for="(component, key) in components" :key="key" :is="component" />
```

this method would render the components you passed